# Can't get a specific array structure

Tags: php, arrays, rank

I'm hanging around since hours to get a specific Array and can't figure it out.

I get this start Array with a foreach loop :

```
Array
(
   [0] => Title 1
   [1] => Image 1.jpg
   [2] => Title 2
   [3] => Image 2.png
   [4] => Text 1
)
```

And I have an Array generated to order the 1st Array *(when the user drag and drop elements of the 1st array)*

```
Array
(
   [0] => 1
   [1] => 4
   [2] => 0
   [3] => 2
   [4] => 3
)
```

What I need is to link the VALUES of the 2nd array (1, 4, 0, 2, 3) with the keys of the first Array ([0],[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujj9i.jpg) ...) to **get exactly that** :

```
Array
(
   [1] => Text 1
   [4] => Image 2.png
   [0] => Image 1.jpg
   [2] => Title 1
   [3] => Title 2
)
```

I've tried array_combine but it don't gives me the result above.

I've made a schema to understand the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking each value of the second array and use it as key for the second array to obtain the key for the first array *while* using the second's array order and key the output:

```
$mapped = array();

foreach($arr2 as $value)
{
    $mapped[$value] = $arr1[$arr2[$value]];
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Text 1
    [4] => Image 2.png
    [0] => Image 1.jpg
    [2] => Title 1
    [3] => Title 2
)
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/H2tUZQ)

Comment: Glad it helped. I think the crossing of keys and values in your original data made this hard to understand, it took me some time as well to find out how you combine the data.

Comment: Yes I know, it tooks me much more time to understand how to explain my problem :p

Answer (score 4):

Here is some pseudo-code (<del>I copy pasted and was too lazy to correct it to be valid PHP</del> I corrected it):

```
<?php
$items = Array
(
   0 => 'Title 1',
   1 => 'Image 1.jpg',
   2 => 'Title 2',
   3 => 'Image 2.png',
   4 => 'Text 1',
);
$order = Array
(
   0 => 1,
   1 => 4,
   2 => 0,
   3 => 2,
   4 => 3,
);

foreach ($order as $itemPosition) {
    $sorted[] = $items[ $itemPosition ];
}

// optionally 
ksort($sorted);
var_dump($sorted);
```

Of course this is assuming your `$order` array has the keys in order. If it doesn't you may want to do a `ksort` on it too before you do the `foreach`.

http://codepad.org/Lq8iw29w